# Perform principal factor analysis using Neural Network in python

Tags: python, deep-learning, factor-analysis

I have an assignment where I have to apply PFA( principal factor analysis) on a dataset using neural network, I know how to apply using sci-kit learn library but I don't know how to perform PFA on a given dataset using neural network.
Is there any python module that I can use?